# Get IP of HTTP request in Casablanca

Tags: c++, windows, http, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have a small server that listens to http requests using Casablanca / cpprestsdk. I've seen that other APIs provide this feature of retrieving client's IP, but after foraging the Internet and the sdk, well.. here I am.

Any help plz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merged to master a few days ago:

- `request.get_remote_address()`

(ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/pull/507)